# Is it true that $f: S\to S$ be a function: $(f \circ f)$ is bijejective if, and only if $f$ is bijective?

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Let $f
>  :S\rightarrow S$
>     be a function.  Show that $f\circ f$
>     is bijective if, and only if, $f$
>     is bijective.

**My solution.**

If $f\circ f$
  is bijective if, and only if, $f$
  is bijective and $f$
  is bijective if, and only if $f\circ f$
  is bijective. Suppose $f\circ f
  :S\rightarrow S$
  is bijective if and only if $f$
  is bijective. We know that $f\circ f$
  is a fuction. Suppose $x = y$, then we know that :

$$f\circ f
  (x) = f\circ f
  (y)$$

$$f(f(x)) = f(f(y))$$

This implies that $f(x) = f(y)$. Hence $f$ is a function.

- We know that $f\circ f$
  is injective. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then applying $f$ again we have $f(f(x)) = f(f(y)) \Longrightarrow
   f\circ f
    (x) = f\circ f
    (y) \Longrightarrow
   x=y$. Hence $f$ is injective.
- Let $y\in
   S$. We know that $f\circ f$
  is surjective so there exists an $x \in
   S$. such that $f\circ f
    (x) = y$ and $f(f(x)) = y$. Since $f$ is mapped from $S$ to $S$, then $f(x)\in
   S$.

Denote $f(x) = z$, then $f(z) = y$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

So $f$ is a function, injective and surjective, thus $f$ is bijective which implies that $f\circ f$
  is bijective.

Can anyone provide me with some feedback?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* Let $f\colon A\to B$, $g\colon B\to C$ be functions. If $g\circ f$ is injective then $f$ is injective. If $g\circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

- Injective: $f: S\hookrightarrow S \iff \Big(\forall x,y\in S: f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b\Big)$

  $$\begin{align}\because f: S\hookrightarrow S & \iff \Big(\forall f(x),f(y)\in S: f(f(x))=f(f(y)) \implies f(x)=f(y)\Big) \\ & \iff \Big(\forall x,y \in S: f\circ f(x)=f\circ f(y)\implies x=y\Big) \\ \therefore f: S\hookrightarrow S &\iff f\circ f : S\hookrightarrow S & \end{align}$$
- Surjective: $f: S\twoheadrightarrow S \iff \Big(\forall x \in S, \exists y\in S: f(y)=x \Big)$

$$\begin{align}\because f: S\twoheadrightarrow S & \iff \Big(\forall f(y)\in S, \exists f(z) \in F : f(f(z))=f(y)\Big)\\ & \iff \Big(\forall x\in S, \exists z \in S: f\circ f(z)= x\Big) \\\therefore f: S\twoheadrightarrow S & \iff f\circ f: S\twoheadrightarrow S\end{align}$$

- Bijective: $f:S \leftrightarrow S \iff f:S \hookrightarrow S \bigwedge f:S \twoheadrightarrow S$

$$\therefore f:S\leftrightarrow S \iff f\circ f: S \leftrightarrow S$$

Comment: Your notations are not standard at all. $\hookrightarrow$ (or $\rightarrowtail$) and $\twoheadrightarrow$ are much more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (different approach than Hagen): f is bijective if and only if it is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you explicitly asked for feedback, here you go: I rewrote your answer and made some remarks.

Let $f: S \to S$ be a function. We prove that $f \circ f$ is bijective if, and only if, $f$ is.

Firstly, suppose that $f \circ f$ is bijective. We prove that $f$ is then also bijective.

[Why do you show that $f$ is a function? The first assumption you made is that $f$ IS a function. Furthermore, could you elaborate on why $f\big(f(x)\big) = f\big(f(y)\big) \implies f(x) = f(y)$?]

We know that $f\circ f$ is injective. Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then applying $f$ again we have $$f\big(f(x)\big) = f\big(f(y)\big) \implies f \circ f(x) = f\circ f(y) \implies x = y \, .$$ Hence $f$ is injective.

Now let $y\in S$. We know that $f \circ f$ is surjective so there exists an $x\in S$ such that $f \circ f(x) = y$ and $f\big(f(x)\big) = y$. Since $f$ is mapped from $S$ to $S$, we have $f(x) \in S$. Denoting $f(x) = z$, we have $f(z) = y$. Hence $f$ is surjective.

We now conclude that $f$ is bijective if $f \circ f$ is bijective.

So far so good for the proof of $f \circ f$ is bijective $"\implies"$ $f$ is bijective.

To do list: show the other direction $f$ is bijective $"\implies"$ $f \circ f$ is bijective.

Answer (score 0):

> For a function $f:S\to S$ be a function: $f\circ f$ is bijective if, and only if, $f$ is bijective.
>
> MY SOLUTION:
>
> If $f\circ f$ is bijective if, and only if, $f$ is bijective and $f$ is bijective if, and only if $f\circ f$ is bijective.

This appears to be what you are trying to demonstrate.  It is also redundant.  "If and only if" is symmetric.  Perhaps you should say something like:

"We shall show that $f\circ f$ is bijective if $f$ is bijective, and that $f$ is bijective if $f\circ f$ is bijective."

> Suppose $f\circ f:S\to S$ is bijective if and only if $f$ is bijective. We know that $f\circ f$ is a function.

Don't assume your conclusion unless you are attempting to demonstrate a contradiction.

> Suppose $x=y$, then we know that :
>
> $$f\circ f(x)=f\circ f(y)$$
>
> $$f(f(x))=f(f(y))$$
>
> This implies that $f(x)=f(y)$. Hence $f$ is a function.

**How** is *that* implied?

What you need to show here is that *if* $f$ is injective *then* it follows that $f\circ f$ is too.

- *If* $f$ is injective then, by definition:

  - $\forall a,b\in S, f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$.
- By substitution, $f(x)=a, f(y)=b$, then

  - $\forall f(x),f(y)\in S, f(f(x))=f(f(y))\implies f(x)=f(y)$
- Now, since $f:S\to S$ then $\forall x\in S, f(x)\in S$ so:

  - $\forall x,y\in S, f(f(x))=f(f(y))\implies f(x)=f(y)$
- And if $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$ then:

  - $\forall x,y\in S, f(f(x))=f(f(y))\implies x=y$
- Which is what we needed to show.

> We know that $f\circ f$ is injective. Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$. Then applying $f$ again we have $f(f(x))=f(f(y))\implies f\circ f(x)=f\circ f(y)\implies x=y$. Hence $f$ is injective.

We don't *know* that $f\circ f$ is injective.  But you can show that *if* it is, *then* *f* has to be too.

> Let $y\in S$. We know that $f\circ f$ is surjective so there exists an $x\in S$. such that $f\circ f(x)=y$ and $f(f(x))=y$. Since $f$ is mapped from S to S, then $f(x)\in S$.
>
> Denote $f(x)=z$, then $f(z)=y$. Hence f is surjective.

Again we don't *know* that $f\circ f$ is surjective. But you have shown that *if* it is *then* $f$ must be.

> So $f$ is a function, injective and surjective, thus $f$ is bijective which implies that $f\circ f$ is bijective.

You seem to have missed the step where you show this to be so.

> CAN ANYONE PLEASE ME FEEDBACK ON MY SOLUTION

Overall you do seem to know *what* you are trying to do.  You just don't seem to be able to express it.  Work on how you phrase things.  (Mostly, if you *assume* something you don't "know" it.)